# Keep connection open for multiple web service requests

Tags: java, web-services, connection, connection-pooling, keep-alive

I would have question regarding web services. Let's say I have webservice client that has to perform under high load. And I cannot use another technology.

Is it possible somehow to keep the connection open for all requests, to avoid overhead when establishing new tcp/ip connections? And in case of managed environment, is it possible having kind of pooled web service connection as it is the case of jdbc connections or JCA??

I am currently working with stubs generated by sun's wsimport and cannot see any possibility how to keep the connection open.

thanks for comments

Comment: checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143922/axis-web-service-keep-alive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Keep-Alive seems to be your answer.

Check these [websites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#HTTP_Keepalive) for [details](http://www.io.com/~maus/HttpKeepAlive.html).

Comment: sure, but how to set it up, as I dont have access to underlying socket?

Comment: check the documentation. which classes are you using to generate http requests?

Comment: Or, locally proxy it... at the client end, run a proxy capable of forwarding the requests over a single connection.  That way your one-request-per-connections are done locally, which will be much faster than across the network.

Comment: by default all connections in HTTP 1.1 are automatically keep-alive enabled, until mnetioned otherwise as "Connection: close"